# UIDynamicAnimator in swift ios 7

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uicollisionbehavior, uidynamicanimator

My iPad application have one page needed to develop with UIDynamicAnimator. I added some piece of code below shown. Its perfectly work in iOS8 as per my need, but fails on iOS7. I am not getting repeated call to delegate when forcefully changing the frame to bouncing.

```
private var bounceCount:Int = 0
private var animator:UIDynamicAnimator!
private var animateWithBounce:Bool = Yes

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

// Do any additional setup.
if(self.animateWithBounce==Yes) {

self.hideAnimationViews()

var rect:CGRect = self.bounceView.frame
rect.origin.y = 319
self.bounceView.frame = rect
self.bounceCount = 0

var animator:UIDynamicAnimator = UIDynamicAnimator(referenceView: self.bounceContainerView)

var gravityBehavior:UIGravityBehavior = UIGravityBehavior(items: [self.bounceView])
gravityBehavior.gravityDirection = CGVector(dx: 0.0, dy: -1.0)
gravityBehavior.magnitude = 1.0
animator.addBehavior(gravityBehavior)

var collisionBehavior:UICollisionBehavior = UICollisionBehavior(items: [self.bounceView])
collisionBehavior.translatesReferenceBoundsIntoBoundary = Yes;
collisionBehavior.collisionDelegate = self;
animator.addBehavior(collisionBehavior)

var elasticityBehavior:UIDynamicItemBehavior = UIDynamicItemBehavior(items: [self.bounceView])
elasticityBehavior.elasticity = 0.8;
animator.addBehavior(elasticityBehavior)

self.animator = animator 
  }
}

// MARK: - UICollisionBehaviorDelegate methods

func collisionBehavior(behavior: UICollisionBehavior, endedContactForItem item: UIDynamicItem, withBoundaryIdentifier identifier: NSCopying) {
    var rect:CGRect = self.bounceView.frame

    if(self.bounceCount==0) {
        rect.origin.y = 79.25
    }
    else if(self.bounceCount==1)    {
        rect.origin.y = 19.25
    }
    else if(self.bounceCount==2)    {
        rect.origin.y = 09.25
    }
    else if(self.bounceCount==3)   {
        self.startAnimationOnViews()
    }

    self.bounceView.frame = rect

    bounceCount = bounceCount+1
}

// MARK: -

private func hideAnimationViews()
{
//some views hided here
}

private func startAnimationOnViews()
{
UIView.animateKeyframesWithDuration(duration, delay: delay, options: options, animations: {

UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(0, relativeDuration: time1, animations: {
//some views showing on first time slot
})

UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(time1, relativeDuration: time2, animations: {
//some views showing on second time slot
})

}, completion: {finished in
//recursive call
})
}
```

*I am using XCode 6.1.0, app compatibility from iOS7. Base SDK iOS 8.1*

```
var Yes:Bool { return true }
var No:Bool { return false }
```

These are globally shared in app like macro or something for better readability

Thanks for support in advance.

Comment: Your code looks fine (obviously). Could you show the part that is failing?

Comment: The failer part is on collisionDelegate. I made some frame changes for bouncing the view several times as per my need. The delegate is not calling when with ios7 swift. :( but working well with ios8. Hope you got my issue. Thank you...

Comment: Okay, I'll say it again. _Show the actual code that you think is failing._ I'm willing to copy and paste and test your code for you, but I am not going to just write my own code from scratch just to help you.

Comment: I modified the code piece above mentioned. Thank you.

Comment: Okay, let me ask you this: `collisionBehavior.translatesReferenceBoundsIntoBoundary = Yes;` What is `Yes`?

Comment: var Yes:Bool { return true }
var No:Bool { return false }

Global shared for easily understanding

Comment: Okay, I ran your code and `collisionBehavior` delegate method is called. What's the problem at your end?

Comment: Once first bounce is finished, I forcefully repeating this with changing the frame for 3 times. Its worked in iOS8, but not in iOS7. That was the problem.

Comment: I know that. That's because what you were doing was always illegal. I was getting to that! - Now do you see why you need to post your code? Your problem statement was wrong. Your code _is_ called. But your code is _wrong_. You need to _show_ the code if you want to be helped.

Comment: Sorry, I didnt get you. what part of my code seems illegal? I am ready to change it. Please clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
self.bounceView.frame = rect
```

You are changing the frame of a view under the control of the dynamic animator, behind the dynamic animator's back. That is illegal. I'm surprised your code *ever* worked. The whole point of the dynamic animator is that *it* is the one setting the frame of the views that it controls.

To do this in a way that doesn't escape the notice of the dynamic animator, simply call `updateItemUsingCurrentState`. That's what it's for.

Comment: Ok now I got your point. Thanks a lot for the patience and the time you gave me. I will change the code in the way that the animator handles everything related to the view.

Comment: I'm sorry to bang on this, but the original problem statement here really makes me angry: "I am not getting any delegate call from UICollisionBehavior from animator." "Is swift for iOS7 supports UIDynamicAnimator?" The delegate _is_ being called. It's just not working as you hope - because what you're doing is wrong. This tendency to blame the system (oh, Swift doesn't support UIDynamicAnimator) rather than yourself is too widespread. No one can learn to program without understanding that the compiler/runtime _knows more than you do_. Sorry, I'll get off my soapbox now.

Comment: Also UIKit Dynamics shouldn't be used that way. You don't tell how many times the item should bounce. Instead you manipulate the item's elasticity, gravity etc. Think about your items like a real-world objects. Should the ball _always_ bounce 3 times when you drop it? No, the number of bounces depends on the height from which you dropped the ball, on ball's initial velocity, its elasticity and the ground's elasticity.